# Jackson 2.4.3 conflicting creators

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following use case: tons of my ObjRef subclasses are of this form (code simplified):

```
public class PlatformRef extends ObjRef {
   public PlatformRef() {}
    public PlatformRef(long id) {}
    public PlatformRef(Long id) {);
}
```

When deserializing (I have an array of these classes in the object to be deserialized, my mapper uses default typing)

```
    ...
    "platforms" : [ {
        "id" : 20001,
        "name" : "my_platformRef_name",
        "idAsLong" : 20001
      }, {
        "id" : 30001,
        "name" : null,
        "idAsLong" : 30001
      } ]
    ...
```

jackson 2.4.3 throws: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting long creators

I've tried using ValueInstantiators#findValueInstantiator to point to a custom instantiator for these ObjRef subclasses.

It fails because BasicDeserializerFactory#findValueInstantiator first finds all possible ctors of the bean (where it fails as above) and only then tries to find the ones defined by the user.

How can I sort this out because:

1. I can not change the classes, so I can not use annotations
2. There is a big number of these classes, using JsonIgnore/JSonCreator mixins would work but is ugly

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it using a customized AnnotationIntrospector:

```
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
    @Override
    public Object findValueInstantiator(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        if (ObjRef.class.isAssignableFrom(ac.getAnnotated())) {
            return new StdCtorValueInstantiator(ac);
        }
        return super.findValueInstantiator(ac);
    }
});

private static class StdCtorValueInstantiator extends ValueInstantiator {

    private AnnotatedClass annotated;

    public StdCtorValueInstantiator(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        annotated = ac;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValueTypeDesc() {
        return "Subclass_of_ObjRef";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canCreateUsingDefault() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object createUsingDefault(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        try {
            return annotated.getDefaultConstructor().getAnnotated().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new IOException("Could not create an instance of " + annotated.getAnnotated()
                    + " using the default c-tor");
        }
    }

}
```